# MATLAB compute length of an integer

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compute the length of an integer.

For example:

```
a = 1.1234; b = 33; c = 100; d = -222;
e = lengthint([a,b,c,d])
```

Expected output:

```
e =  1    2    3    3
```

I tried using this:

```
e = max(ceil(log10(abs([a,b,c,d]))),1)
```

but this is the output:

```
e =  1    2    2    3
```

So there is a problem with numbers that are multiples of 10.

Comment: Don't take the  `ceil` . `floor(log10(number))` will give you the decade you want, then "add one" to find the number of digits in your integer.  Hmmph, guess I should have looked at the answers before commenting. :-)  Sorry, @Divikar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
A = [a,b,c,d]
lens = floor(log10(abs(A)))+1
lens(lens<0) = 0 %// Assuming that 0.xx numbers to have zero lengths
```

Sample runs:

Case #1:

```
>> A = [0.00001234, 1.1234, 33, 10,  -222];
>> lens = floor(log10(abs(A)))+1;
>> lens(lens<0) = 0
lens =
     0     1     2     2     3
```

Case #2:

```
>> A = [-0.00001234, 1.1234 33, 10,  -222, 0];
>> lens = floor(log10(abs(A)))+1;
>> lens(lens<0) = 0
lens =
     0     1     2     2     3     0
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to convert them to strings and check the length:

```
 cellfun(@(x)length(num2str(abs(fix(x)))),{a,b,c,d});
```

the only complication is that you need cells to keep your strings separate.

Output from @Divakar's [example input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32968412/5067311):

```
>> a1 = 0.00001234; a2 = 1.1234; b = 33; c = 100; d = -222;
>> cellfun(@(x)length(num2str(abs(fix(x)))),{a1,a2,b,c,d})

ans =

     1     1     2     3     3
```

so it will obviously not give 0 for the 1e-5 case.

Comment: `1` seemed like a good choice for such a `1e-5` case, but I wasn't 100% sure what must be the output for such case.

Comment: @Divakar, I guess it's up to convention. I'd call 0 an integer of length 1, but I can easily imagine OP thinking otherwise:)

Comment: Yep, I use this approach to up- or down- scale doubles:  `x = 1.0034; y = str2num(strrep(num2str(x),'.','')); expo = log10(y/x) `  and so on